# How do I set the color of a face using the SurfaceTool?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have been using `surface_tool.set_color` to try and set vertex colors, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is an example that can be used to replicate the issue:

```
extends MeshInstance3D

func _ready():
    create_colored_cube()

func create_colored_cube():
    # Define cube data
    var vertices = [
        Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
        Vector3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5), Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Vector3(0.5, 0.5, -0.5)
    ]
    var faces = [
        [3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 5, 4], [1, 2, 6, 5], [2, 3, 7, 6], [4, 7, 3, 0]
    ]
    var colors = [
        Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN
    ]

    # Create a new ArrayMesh and SurfaceTool
    var mesh = ArrayMesh.new()
    var surface_tool = SurfaceTool.new()
    surface_tool.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES)

    # Loop through each face
    for i in range(faces.size()):
        # Set the color for the vertices of this face
        surface_tool.set_color(colors[i])
        # Add the vertices for this face
        for j in range(4):
            surface_tool.add_vertex(vertices[faces[i][j]])
        # Add two triangles for this face
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4)
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4 + 1)
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4 + 2)
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4)
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4 + 2)
        surface_tool.add_index(i*4 + 3)

    # Generate normals and tangents
    surface_tool.generate_normals()
    surface_tool.generate_tangents()

    # Commit to the mesh
    surface_tool.commit(mesh)

    # Set the MeshInstance's mesh
    self.mesh = mesh
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var material = StandardMaterial3D.new()
material.vertex_color_use_as_albedo = true
self.set_surface_override_material(0, material)
```

You have to add a meterial to the mesh as well